# Searching in Flutter Inspector

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have a problem with searching inside Widgets in Flutter Inspector. I unchecked “Enable embedding DevTools in the Flutter Inspector tool window” in settings. But I can't search the desired properties in the popup.
I  clicked inside this area with the properties, typed a few letters and the search disappears and it starts typing in the code instead. How can I fix this problem?

I will be glad to help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.